# prototype.js innerHTML does not work with IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototypejs

Apparently IE (10) does not like this piece of code:

```
$('size_list').innerHTML = '<form id="dropdown_menu"><select id="dropdown_options"></select></form>';
```

The dropdown menu is not being generated. I get an `Unknown Run Time` error, which is really "helpful". The next line of code is:

```
$('dropdown_options').innerHTML = '<option>Choose size</option>';
```

But when I debug - I don't even get till here.

The `'size_list'` element is just a simple empty `div`:

```
<div id="size_list" style="float:right; margin-top: -22px;"></div>
```

I found some info that states `.innerHTML` does not really work with IE, but I have many other places in my script where I assign even bigger chunks of HTML to `div` elements, through `.innerHTML` and all works. Except the upper stated assigning of dropdown form.

Comment: I'll start with.. your selectors are missing the `#`

Comment: Are you sure that you are using jQuery? Those snippets look like [prototype.js](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar/) calls to me.

Comment: @Douglas - you are right. I got mistaken because of some other stuff. Anyway - yes, I am using `prototype.js` here.

Comment: That would have been handy to know... next time make clear which library you're using

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#size_list').html('<form id="dropdown_menu"><select id="dropdown_options"></select></form>');
$('#dropdown_options').html('<option>Choose size</option>');
```

You can't use a hammer as a wrench...

Or use `document.getElementById('size_list').innerHTML` or use `$('#size_list').html()`

Don't forget to put a `#` before an id selector in jQuery and a `.` before a class selector otherwise jQuery tries to find a `<size_list>` tag which won't exist in the DOM tree.

Comment: The OP is using Prototype, so why show a jQuery solution?

Comment: Because he only added javascript tag when he asked initially

Answer (score 2):

First of all, while it may be convenient to add select options using the direct insert html methods, it rarely works universally. The bulletproof way to add options to a select is to build them up one at a time in a loop, assigning their value and label the old-fashioned way.

```
var form = new Element('form', {id: 'dropdown_menu' });
var picker = new Element('select', {id: 'dropdown_options', size: 1 });
$('size_list').insert(form);
form.insert(picker);
picker.options[picker.options.length] = new Option('Choose size', '');
// want to add a list of elements in a loop?
$w('Foo Bar Baz').each(function(val){
  picker.options[picker.options.length] = new Option(val, val);
});
```

IE has never dealt with modifications of the select element gracefully at all, this goes back to IE 5 when I first started trying to do this sort of thing.